# Incomplete html attribute when using rvest

Tags: rvest

I'm using rvest to scrape from https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/therapists/m5g ; in particular what I'm after is the  `data-myurl`  html attribute in the  `div`  tag with  `id="results-page"` . If you view source you'll see there's only one  `div`  with  `id="results-page"` . The  `data-myurl`  attribute looks like the main URL except with the addition of a string of numbers separated by a period and underscore, like so

```
<div id="results-page" data-myurl="https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/therapists/m5g?sid=1510588046.3852_2969">
```

The numbers you see will likely be different. To try and extract it, I use the following code:

```
require(rvest)
fsa <- read_html('https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/therapists/m5g')
fsa %>% html_node('div #results-page') %>% html_attr("data-myurl")
```

However, this returns only

```
[1] "https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/therapists/m5g"
```

So everything after the original URL is missing. It doesn't seem like a JS thing since I don't see any  `script`  tags when I view source. Does anyone know what these numbers in the URL actually are and how to extract them? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the number? It contains no information about the content in the page.

Comment: If you click the "next" button at the bottom of the list to access the next 20 (or fewer) entries you'll see the number appear in the URL for that next page.  If I can grab the number off the first page I can directly access later pages

Comment: you can access the next page without that number - https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/therapists/m5g?rec_next=21 gets you there

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with rvest.

The page you're trying to scrape is dynamically rendered after loading the initial page. The content itself is always the same, but the sid numbers change the ordering of the results after loading the page. The sid changes on every visit and page reload.

I suspect this was done to avoid a market bias when searching for a therapist.

If you really want the sid number, you need to use a tool that handles dynamic pages like casperjs.
(http://casperjs.org/)

Edit:

Alternatively, if it has to be done in R then you can use RSelenium.  (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/)

The relevant starting point would be here: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html

Comment: Good to know what purpose they're serving, thanks for the links